# VB.net Override OCX onclick event

Tags: vb.net, ocx

I using an OCX for an ipcam in my program. when you double click on the control it goes into full screen mode. I want to prevent this. I have this event in my form. I there anything Ican do at this point to prevent the click event from going to the ocx?

```
Private Sub AxGSViewerX1_ClickSel(sender As Object, e As AxGSViewerXLib._DGSViewerXEvents_ClickSelEvent) Handles AxGSViewerX1.ClickSel
    Console.WriteLine("click")

End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: What are the properties or methods of `e` ? Do they contain anything like `cancel` ? Also, is there a `doubleclick` event?

Comment: nothing like cancel or handled..  it says doubleclick is not a vaild event

Comment: Then you may have to create your own control by inheriting from the OCX and overriding click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom control which would inherit from the OCX. Then you can override  the event e.g.

```
Protected Overrides Sub ClickSel(ByVal e As _DGSViewerXEvents_ClickSelEvent)
    'Do nothing here.
End Sub
```